# Is it possible to login to a Flutter Windows app with Firebase?

Tags: flutter, windows, authentication

I am analyzing how to log in to Flutter for Windows applications. If you would be so kind as to help me by answering the question or tell me if you know of other alternatives.

Comment: Well now `cloud_firestore` supports windows, also there are many services from Firebase, you can check the pub.dev, and I hope there are alternatives can be found.